# EF Core limit load prior data aggregation / at include time

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, .net-core

I have the following data structure:

```
Location { Id, Name }
MeetingRoom { Id, Name, Capacity, CreatedAt }
Meeting {Id, Subject, StartTime, EndTime }
Attendee { Id, Name }
```

The relationship is:

- A Location has *many* MeetingRooms
- A MeetingRoom has *one* location
- A MeetingRoom has *many* Meetings
- A Meeting has *one* MeetingRoom
- A Meeting has *many* attendees
- An attendee has *one* meeting

My query is as follows:

```
 var result = _reader.Query()
                    .Where(location => location.Id == query.Id)
                    .Include(location => location.MeetingRooms)
                        .ThenInclude(room => room.Meetings)
                    .Include(location => location.MeetingRooms)
                        .ThenInclude(room => room.Meetings)
                            .ThenInclude(meeting => meeting.Meeting.Attendees)
                    .Select(location => new LocationWithMeetingRoomsView
                    {
                        Name = location.Name,
                        MeetingRooms = location.MeetingRooms.Select(room => new MeetingRoomWithMeetingsView
                        {
                            Name = room.Name,
                            Capacity = room.Capacity,
                            TotalMeetings = room.Meetings.Count(),
                            AvailableHours = (DateTime.Today.Subtract(room.CreatedAt).TotalDays),
                            MeetingHours = room.Meetings.Sum(meeting => meeting.Meeting.EndTime.Subtract(meeting.Meeting.StartTime).Hours),
                            AverageAttendees = Math.Round(room.Meetings.Average(meeting => meeting.Meeting.Attendees.Count()), 2),
                        }).ToList()
                    })
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The above will produce an output like this:

```
{
    Name: "Denmark",
    MeetingRooms: [
        { 
            Name: "MeetingRoom 1",
            Capacity: 4,
            TotalMeetings: 947,
            AvailablHours: 245,
            MeetingHours = 2212.2,
            AverageAttendees = 2.84
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Notice the issue that `TotalMeetings` and the corrosponding `MeetingHours` is very high, because it's *all* meeting entities for that room from all time. I toyed with this idea:

```
TotalMeetings = room.Meetings.Count(meeting => meeting.Meeting.StartTime >= query.From && meeting.Meeting.EndTime <= query.To),
```

So "limit the retrieved entities to a specific time period", but that gives me another problem:

```
AverageAttendees = Math.Round(room.Meetings.Average(meeting => meeting.Meeting.Attendees.Count()), 2)
```

Would need to have the same filtering, else the average amount of attendees would be for all meetings and not just the filtered ones, let alone I suspect each time I do the inline where trick, I create a subquery.

So is it possible to define the where/filter clause on include time such as:

```
.Include(room => room.Meetings).Where(meeting => meeting.StartTime >= query.From && meeting.EndTime <= query.To)
.ThenInclude(....
```

Or do I have to pull the query a bit apart and do it in multiple queries and cache the result?

Comment: The `Include`s will be ignored anyway, because the query produces a projection (`new LocationWithMeetingRoomsView`).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do as you suggest, place a where clause on the include.

Comment: Could you examplify. If I write  Query().Where(location => location.Id == query.Id).Include(location => location.MeetingRooms).ThenInclude(room => room.Meetings).Where(/* THIS PART */) then I only have access to the location in the anonymous function, and not the meetings.

Comment: @bilpor Did you ever actually *try* to use a `Where` clause in an `Include`?

Comment: yes I have, From the result set you would need to perform another linq statement on the data, but you should still be able to get to it.

Comment: Also when trying to extract data from the result. You may have to either cast or us the 'as objecttype' keyword

Comment: Well, maybe you should show some code, because to me it's not clear what you mean by *place a where clause on the include*. I read it as `Include(location => location.MeetingRooms.Where(r => ...) )`, which isn't possible.